# How to drop shadow over a layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon

I am trying to reproduce a bent-like shape. For this, I created two circles: one over the other one. Then, create a layer mask to hide the unnecessary part of the circle.

Now I am trying to drop its shadow over the circle which is under. However, the shadow is going out of that circle and I dont know how to get the shadow dropped in the bottom circle

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this stuff I´d use a clipping mask. Right click on the Layer that should not "overflow" and select "Create Clipping mask". Note that the layer has to be directly over the circle layer. Just play around with it and maybe you´ll discover a whole range of new options :)

P.S: I´d create a circle like that in Illustrator so you have the fully editable Vector Shape. Plus you´d only have to lay one shape over the other and use the Pathfinder to create something like that, I personally don´t like Layer Masks in this case because there´s much that can go wrong, for example when you scale stuff, but that´s just my 2 cent on this matter :D

Answer (score 1):

1) Place your shadow layer **right over** Ellipse 1
2) Right click shadow layer in a Layers panel and pick **Create Clipping Mask**.